# Criar um arquivo temporário de select para repetir em outras paginas

Tags: php, mysql

É possível fazer só um processamento de consulta select no php e mysql e usar o resultado em páginas que são continuações?

```
Exemplo:
Pagina 1 = faz select de dados, mostra o resultado e reserva.
Pagina 1-1 = mostra o reservado
Pagina 1-2 = mostra o reservado
Pagina 1-3 = mostra o reservado
```

Comment: É possivel com `JS`

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, vc pode colocar um exemplo, pf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo uma logica basica, fazemos o `SQL` e retornamos um `json`

```
// PHP
$retorno = array();
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela");
$sql->execute();
$retorno['dados'] = $sql->fetchAll();

die(json_encode($retorno));
```

Feito isso, ao recuperarmos o `json`, teriamos algo similar a isso.

```
[
  {
    "Nome": "Rafael Augusto"
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Geo"
  }
]
```

Agora poderiamos armazenar o resultado em um `sessionStorage` para recuperar em cada pagina.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('retorno', JSON.stringify(retornoPHP))
```

Seguindo mais ou menos essa logica, você tem seu retorno e pode acessa-lo de qualquer pagina. Claro que existem outras formas de fazer, mas estou dando esse exemplo.

Comment: Rafael, vou tentar incluir e logo posto o resultado. Obrigado !!!

Comment: Eu rodei a 1ª parte e o  resultado é duplicado. É assim mesmo?

Comment: $retorno = array();
$sql = $pdo->prepare("select perg from per WHERE idn2={$n2} AND idrec={$rec} LIMIT 5");
$sql->execute();
$retorno['dados'] = $sql->fetchAll();
die(json_encode($retorno));

Comment: Não entendi, resultado duplicado?

Comment: {"dados":[{"perg":"D\u00favida- fiz um licor de chocolate e depois..." ,"0":"D\u00favida- fiz um licor de chocolate e depois....

Comment: reduzi o texto e coloquei só um duplicado.

Comment: É assim mesmo, você pode trocar por `fetch`

Comment: Com fetch mostrou só 1 registro e continua duplicado

Comment: Pode usar `fetchAll()` mesmo, e não é duplicado, é apenas representação de retorno de dados. Se você prestar atenção, os indices são diferentes, ele tras da forma que está no banco e numerado.

Comment: OK, vou para a 2ª etapa. Peço paciência para um novo velho aprendiz (70 anos). Vou estudar sobre sessionStorage. Depois posto como ficou rsrs.